# Webpack doesn't process TypeScript-based node_modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, babeljs, webpacker, babel-loader

I stuck for a while about importing `.ts` or `.tsx` files from the `node_modules` folder into the app. It turns out `babel` is unable to process typescript-based things from there.

Here is an example:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ui-kit/components/Link/index.tsx 32:1
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   arrowName = 'down',
|   linkColor
> }: IProps) => {
|   const _handleClick = (e) => {
|     onClick && onClick(e);
 @ ./node_modules/src/index.ts 10:0-37 25:0-44:2
```

Here is my loader for TS|TSX:

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules\/(?!(@ui-kit)\/).*/],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          allowTsInNodeModules: true,
          compilerOptions: {
            target: __DEV__ ? 'ES2019' : 'ES5'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's open the `environmet.js` file. Then, remove general loaders:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
environment.loaders.delete('file')
environment.loaders.delete('babel')
environment.loaders.delete('nodeModules')
```

Add your own by config option:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
environment.config.module = {
  ...environment.config.module,
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules\/(?!(@ui-kit)\/).*/],
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            allowTsInNodeModules: true,
            compilerOptions: {
              target: 'ES2019'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'javascript/auto',
      test: /\.json$/,
      use: ['json-loader']
    },
    // FILE/IMAGES
    {
      test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff']
    },
    {
      test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2']
    },
    {
      test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['file-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype']
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream']
    },
    {
      test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['file-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]']
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,
      use: ['url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      use: ['url-loader?limit=8192']
    }
  ]
}
```